# How can Julia stdout be redirected to IPython console?

Tags: python, julia, ipython, pycall

I am using PyJulia to call a Julia function in a Python script. The Julia function is a simulation which continuously prints to `stdout`, updating a progress bar and some debugging information as it runs. When I run the script in Spyder, Julia's `stderr` automatically redirects to the IPython console, but `stdout` does not. I have found documentation on redirecting Julia `stdout` to a file using `redirect_stdout` and on using `subprocess.Popen` to pipe something into a Python script. Can the two be combined to pipe Julia's `stdout` to Spyder's IPython console for live progress monitoring? If so, how? If not, how can I achieve this instead?

Comment: Couldn't you just do `redirect_stdout(stderr) do ... end` on the Julia end?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried that - it doesn't work.